# Online database to use with local application

Tags: java, database

I am making a web application in Java. I want to continue to develop this application even when i dont have administrative privileges on my work laptop. I am unable to install databases on my local system. Are there any free online databases i can use. I want to be able to provide a connection URL and perform transactions like in a local db.

I also want to try and connect to as many different databases as possible to test out my code.

Would in memory dbs need installation? Could there be a work arround there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the down vote man ?!!!  no one asked this question on Stack overflow. It will help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JDBC wrapper for Sqlite.

Check out [Sqlite-JDBC](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), or [this list](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/ComparisonToOtherWrappers).

No installation needed.

---

For online database hosting:

- [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/). Free for a 500mb shared database.
- [Compose.io](https://www.compose.io/) offers MongoDb, ProstgreSQL, RethinkDb and more. 30 day trial.
- Lots of options for MySql, eg. http://www.freemysqlhosting.net/.
- Many more, Google will help you.

---

I Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: It does. Thanks. There is another part to the question though. I want to try different databases if they are available online.. like mongoDB and Mysql,Postgres. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of free-ish online databases I would also recommend to mount your own local home server, install the databases you want to try there and then publish your server to the internet either checking its public IP everytime before you leave to work or using a service like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) for a local VPN or [no-ip](http://www.noip.com) to have a domain so you can connect to these databases from work.

You can download and install some common free databases like:

- **[MySQL Community Edition](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)**
- **[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/download/)**
- **[Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)**
- **[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)**

Comment: i would have done that by now if i could. Its a good suggestion though. Thanks.